Question about Proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry
I have been trying to understand the proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry:

Theorem (Hilbert's Nullstellensatz) Let $K$ be a (not necessarily algebraically closed) field and let $A$ be a finitely generated $K$-algebra. Then $A$ is Jacobson, that is, for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$ we have
$$
\mathfrak p
=\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak m\supset\mathfrak p\\\text{maximal ideal}}}\mathfrak m\,.
$$
If $\mathfrak m\subset A$ is a maximal ideal, the field extension $K\subset A/\mathfrak m$ is finite.
Proof. (Hilbert's Nullstellensatz) Lemma 1.10 implies at once the second assertion: If $\mathfrak m\subset A$ is a maximal ideal, $A/\mathfrak m$ is a field extension of $K$ which is finitely generated as a $K$-algebra.
For the proof of the first assertion we start with a remark. If $L$ is a finite field extension and $\varphi\colon A\to L$ is a $K$-algebra homomorphism, the image of $\varphi$ is an integral domain that is finite over $K$. Thus $\operatorname{Im}\varphi$ is a field by Lemma 1.9 and therefore $\operatorname{Ker}\varphi$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.
We now show that $A$ is Jacobson. Let $\mathfrak p\subset A$ be a prime ideal. Replacing $A$ by $A/\mathfrak p$ it suffices to show that in an integral finitely generated $K$-algebra the intersection of all maximal ideals is the zero ideal. Assume there existed $x\ne0$ that is contained in all maximal ideals of $A$. Then $A[x^{-1}]$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra $\ne0$. Let $\mathfrak n$ be a maximal ideal of $A[x^{-1}]$, then $L:= A[x^{-1}]/\mathfrak n$ is a finite extension of $K$ by the second assertion of the Nullstellensatz. The kernel of the composition $\varphi\colon A\to A[x^{-1}]\to L$ is a maximal ideal by the above remark. But it does not contain $x$. Contradiction.$\,\square$

However, I am having trouble with the line "Assume there existed $x \neq 0$ that is contained in
all maximal ideals of $A$. Then $A[x^{−1}]$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra $\neq 0$". My question is, why do we know that $x$ has an inverse in $A$? We only know $A$ is an integral, finitely-generated $K$-algebra, it is not necessarily a field, so why should the inverse exist?
Any insight would be deeply appreciated :)

The inverse is not in $A$; it is adjoined to $A$ by localization. The integrality (in the sense of "integral domain", not of "integral over $K$"; the author could be clearer here) of $A$ guarantees that $A$ embeds into this localization, so you get no clashes by identifying $A$ with a subring of it.

Why do you ask about $x$ having an inverse in $A$?  If it did then $A[x^{-1}] = A$ and there would be no point in writing $A[x^{-1}]$.

Please do not rely on images only for the crucial parts of your question.

As already pointed out in the comments, $A[x^{-1}]$ is constructed, formally, as an $K$-algebra containing $A$ and an inverse for the non-zero element $x\in A$. This is just the localisation of $A$ at $x$, also denoted $A_x$.
The reduction to the case of integral domains $A$ allows you to consider its field of fractions $Q(A)$, which also is its maximal localisation, and moreover that $A$ is naturally a subring of $Q(A)$. The field of fractions consists of formal expressions $\tfrac ab$ with $a,b\in A$ and $b\ne0$. Contrast this with the definition of the rational numbers from the integers. We can the view $A[x^{-1}]$ as the subalgebra of $Q(A)$ generated by $A$ and $\tfrac 1x=x^{-1}$. Hence $A[x^{-1}]$ consists of elements of the form $\tfrac a{x^n}$ with $a\in A$ and $n\ge0$.
Finally, this "trick" of considering localisations at elements of a given (integral) ring $A$ is very useful in constructing maximal ideals containing or not containing a specified element. Just localise at an element and then consider a maximal ideal in the localisation (whose existence follows from, say, Zorn's Lemma). Since maximal cannot contain units by definition, they cannot contain the specified elements you localised at.
The condition of being Jacobson is actually a strengthening of the following fact from commutative algebra.
Fact. Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $I\le A$ be an ideal. Then
$$
\sqrt{I}
=\bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak p\supset I\\\text{prime ideal}}}\mathfrak p
$$
where $\sqrt{I}=\{x\in A\,|\,x^n\in I\text{ for some }n\ge0\}$ is the radical of $I$.
Proof. One direction is clear since $\sqrt{\mathfrak p}=\mathfrak p$ for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$.
For the converse, one considers w.l.o.g. the case $I=(0)$. If then $x\not\sqrt{(0)}$, that is, $x$ is not nilpotent, the localisation $A_x=A[x^{-1}]$ is non-trivial. One the considers a maximal ideal of $A_x$ whose preimage along $A\to A_x$ is a prime ideal of $A$ not containing $x$.$\,\square$
Observe, that this statement is trivial for prime ideals. However, a Jacobson ring more generally satisfies that every radical is the intersection of all maximal ideals containing the ideal. This gives you the statement you are considering since $\sqrt{\mathfrak p}=\mathfrak p$, as I already mentioned above.
